# Using a template function for a type that is not explicitly instantiated?

Tags: c++, templates, explicit-instantiation

I created the following to try to better understand explicit instantiation of template functions. I was under (what appears to be wrong now) the impression that if you explicitly instantiate a template function, then you can only use the template function for the types that were used during explicit instantiation, which in this case is just `double`.

But here, I used it for `std::string` and the code compiles. Is my understanding incorrect?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
template <typename dim>
void func(dim i) {
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

template void func<double>(double i);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  func<std::string>("123");
}
```

Comment: You should put the template declaration and caller into two different translation units.

Comment: @Nimrod Just to confirm, a single file is a single translation unit, right?

Comment: Roughly yes. Actually it refers to a source file being preprocessed.